# How to retrieve Name value pair from Aem select option via sling model

Tags: model, aem, sling

I have multiple select dropdown where the dropdown(say myLocale) getting saved as String[] under the page. There i can see property  myLocale String [] en,us,gb. I.e option value under component in my page.  Suppose i also want to retrieve the option name as well .how to do that in sling model. I cant see name getting saved under component node under my page.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a number dialog of fields you could be using here which may store data in different formats in the JCR. It would be useful to know which ones you used (resource types) and how your dialog is structured. Ultimately, from the Sling Models' perspective, what matters is the underlying content structure. How is the data saved in the repository once you submit the dialog? Also, please post the code you have tried and describe the result you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The name is usually nothing more than a label to make things more comfortable for the people using the multi select. It is not included in a standard form submission.
You have several options to solve this issue:
1. Instead of just having the value in the value attribute of the option tag, you could make your form editors write down something like "value|label". Once it is written to the repo, you could then devide it. But I think this is not the best solution...
2. Another option - if we are talking about select options for your content page (not for editor dialogs) would be to access the content page and the component - your sling model should have this resource - and then read the value from there.
3. If you should be talking about an editor dialog, try to store the options in a separate file and access that file.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oliver. If you can guide me in terms of how we can due it in AEM/CQ. Here we have name :value pair stored in the component . But as sson as we drag component into the page , the page gets saved with the value of dropdowns (String[])only  and not the name/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a valuemap containing the property name and value as key value pairs of the component or resource. This `ValueMap properties = currentResource.getValueMap();` will give you the valuemap stored in properties which you can then iterate. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sadistic, This will give the name value pair from the component resource. I want the name value pair for the options that has been selected from the dialog and got saved as String [] en,gb,cn under /content/site/MyPage. Here I can see only the values got saved and not the corresponding name  . Tagmanager is used TagID to get the TagNames. Can we use TagManager for the dropdown values or any similar API?

Comment: Wherever your data is getting stored that does not matter. You just have to adapt to an according resource. If you have a proper resource object then you can get the valuemap of the corresponding resource whether its a page property or a string[].